# How to center this checkbox?

Tags: html, css

This is a signup form from MAILCHIMP I'm trying to customize.
I'm almost there, I just need to put the checkbox to the left of the sentence before it.

[image: Screenshot]

I tried using all sorts of "align" commands in CSS with the checkbox object as the class name, also the parent objects it sits inside. No luck. I'm sure I'm missing something simple...

```css
@font-face {
  font-family: museo-sans;
  src: url(/fonts/museosans_300.otf) format("opentype");
  font-display: auto;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 300;
  font-stretch: normal
}

@font-face {
  font-family: museo-sans-bold;
  src: url(/fonts/museosans_700.otf) format("opentype");
  font-display: auto;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-stretch: normal
}

@font-face {
  font-family: bwstretch;
  src: url(/fonts/BWSTRETCH-BLACK.OTF) format("opentype");
  font-display: auto;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 800;
  font-stretch: normal
}

h2 {
  font-family: bwstretch;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 2em !important;
}

* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: none;
  font-family: museo-sans;
  color: #ffc860;
}

body {
  font-size: 1em;
  background-color: #191f43;
  font-family: museo-sans;
}

#wrapper {
  width: 80% overflow: auto;
  /* will contain if #first is longer than #second */
  background-color: #191f43;
}

#first {
  width: 40%;
  float: left;
  /* add this */
  padding-left: 5%;
  background-color: #191f43;
}

#mc_embed_signup {
  width: 60% float:left;
  /* add this */
  overflow: hidden;
  /* if you don't want #second to wrap below #first */
  background-color: #191f43;
  color: #ffc860;
  font-family: museo-sans;
}

#mc-embedded-subscribe-form input[type=checkbox] {
  display: flex;
  width: auto;
}

#mergeRow-gdpr {
  margin-top: 20px;
}

#mergeRow-gdpr fieldset label {
  font-weight: normal;
}

#mc-embedded-subscribe-form .mc_fieldset {
  border: none;
  min-height: 0px;
  padding-bottom: 0px;
}
```

```html
<body>

  <!-- Start MailChimp stuff -->
  <!-- Begin Mailchimp Signup Form -->
  <link href="//cdn-images.mailchimp.com/embedcode/classic-071822.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

  <div id="wrapper">
    <div id="first"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/100"></div>
    <div id="mc_embed_signup">
      <form action="https://opipets.us17.list-manage.com/subscribe/post?u=3fa8d83aedc08e2a8814c787c&amp;id=27f9c81072&amp;v_id=4140&amp;f_id=00bb56e0f0" method="post" id="mc-embedded-subscribe-form" name="mc-embedded-subscribe-form" class="validate" target="_blank"
        novalidate>
        <div id="mc_embed_signup_scroll">
          <h2>Join our Whitelist</h2>
          <div class="indicates-required"><span class="asterisk">*</span> indicates required</div>
          <div class="mc-field-group">
            <label for="mce-EMAIL">Email Address  <span class="asterisk">*</span>
</label>
            <input type="email" value="" name="EMAIL" class="required email" id="mce-EMAIL" required>
          </div>
          <div id="mergeRow-gdpr" class="mergeRow gdpr-mergeRow content__gdprBlock mc-field-group">
            <div class="content__gdpr">

              <p>I agree to receive email communications from Opis Group Ltd</p>
              <br>
              <fieldset class="mc_fieldset gdprRequired mc-field-group" name="interestgroup_field">
                <label class="checkbox subfield" for="gdpr_90860"><input type="checkbox" id="gdpr_90860" name="gdpr[90860]" value="Y" class="av-checkbox gdpr"></label>
              </fieldset>
              <p>Your privacy is our policy. Occasionally, we'll contact you about our products and services, and other content that may be of interest. You can unsubscribe at any time.</p>
            </div>
            <div class="content__gdprLegal">
              <p>We use Mailchimp as our marketing platform. By clicking below to subscribe, you acknowledge that your information will be transferred to Mailchimp for processing. <a href="https://mailchimp.com/legal/terms" target="_blank">Learn more about Mailchimp's privacy practices here.</a></p>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div hidden="true"><input type="hidden" name="tags" value="6456416,6456520"></div>
          <div id="mce-responses" class="clear">
            <div class="response" id="mce-error-response" style="display:none"></div>
            <div class="response" id="mce-success-response" style="display:none"></div>
          </div>
          <!-- real people should not fill this in and expect good things - do not remove this or risk form bot signups-->
          <div style="position: absolute; left: -5000px;" aria-hidden="true"><input type="text" name="b_3fa8d83aedc08e2a8814c787c_27f9c81072" tabindex="-1" value=""></div>
          <div class="clear"><input type="submit" value="Subscribe" name="subscribe" id="mc-embedded-subscribe" class="button"></div>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>

  </div>
  <script type='text/javascript' src='//s3.amazonaws.com/downloads.mailchimp.com/js/mc-validate.js'></script>
  <script type='text/javascript'>
    (function($) {
      window.fnames = new Array();
      window.ftypes = new Array();
      fnames[0] = 'EMAIL';
      ftypes[0] = 'email';
    }(jQuery));
    var $mcj = jQuery.noConflict(true);
  </script>
  <!--End mc_embed_signup-->
  <!-- End MailChimp stuff -->

</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So all i did was wrap it in a span and then flex'ed it. Hope this helped!

```css
@font-face {
    font-family: museo-sans;
    src: url(/fonts/museosans_300.otf) format("opentype");
    font-display: auto;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 300;
    font-stretch: normal
}

@font-face {
    font-family: museo-sans-bold;
    src: url(/fonts/museosans_700.otf) format("opentype");
    font-display: auto;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 700;
    font-stretch: normal
}

@font-face {
    font-family: bwstretch;
    src: url(/fonts/BWSTRETCH-BLACK.OTF) format("opentype");
    font-display: auto;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 800;
    font-stretch: normal
}

h2 {
    font-family: bwstretch;
    text-align: center;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 2em !important;
}

* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: none;
  font-family: museo-sans;
  color: #ffc860;
}

body {
  font-size: 1em;
  background-color: #191f43;
  font-family: museo-sans;
}

#wrapper {
    width: 80%;
    overflow: auto; /* will contain if #first is longer than #second */
    background-color: #191f43;
}

#first {
    width: 40%;
    float:left; /* add this */
    padding-left: 5%;
    background-color: #191f43;
}

#mc_embed_signup {
    width: 60%;
    float:left; /* add this */
    overflow: hidden; /* if you don't want #second to wrap below #first */
    background-color: #191f43;
    color: #ffc860;
    font-family: museo-sans;
}

#mc-embedded-subscribe-form input[type=checkbox]{
    display: flex;
    width: auto;
}

#mergeRow-gdpr {
    margin-top: 20px;
}

#mergeRow-gdpr fieldset label {
    font-weight: normal;
}

#mc-embedded-subscribe-form .mc_fieldset{
    border:none;
    min-height: 0px;
    padding-bottom:0px;}


span{
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/assets/signup.css">
</head>

<body>

    <!-- Start MailChimp stuff -->
    <!-- Begin Mailchimp Signup Form -->
    <link href="//cdn-images.mailchimp.com/embedcode/classic-071822.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

    <div id="wrapper">
        <div id="first"><img src="images/genesis.gif"></div>
        <div id="mc_embed_signup">
            <form
                action="https://opipets.us17.list-manage.com/subscribe/post?u=3fa8d83aedc08e2a8814c787c&amp;id=27f9c81072&amp;v_id=4140&amp;f_id=00bb56e0f0"
                method="post" id="mc-embedded-subscribe-form" name="mc-embedded-subscribe-form" class="validate"
                target="_blank" novalidate>
                <div id="mc_embed_signup_scroll">
                    <h2>Join our Whitelist</h2>
                    <div class="indicates-required"><span class="asterisk">*</span> indicates required</div>
                    <div class="mc-field-group">
                        <label for="mce-EMAIL">Email Address <span class="asterisk">*</span>
                        </label>
                        <input type="email" value="" name="EMAIL" class="required email" id="mce-EMAIL" required>
                    </div>
                    <div id="mergeRow-gdpr" class="mergeRow gdpr-mergeRow content__gdprBlock mc-field-group">
                        <div class="content__gdpr">

                            <--! Span opening -->
                            <span>
                                <label class="checkbox subfield" for="gdpr_90860"><input type="checkbox"
                                    id="gdpr_90860" name="gdpr[90860]" value="Y"
                                    class="av-checkbox gdpr"></label>
                                    <p>I agree to receive email communications from Opis Group Ltd</p>
                                </span> 
<--! Span closing -->
                                <br>
                                <fieldset class="mc_fieldset gdprRequired mc-field-group" name="interestgroup_field">
                                </fieldset>
                            
                            <p>Your privacy is our policy. Occasionally, we'll contact you about our products and
                                services, and other content that may be of interest. You can unsubscribe at any time.
                            </p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="content__gdprLegal">
                            <p>We use Mailchimp as our marketing platform. By clicking below to subscribe, you
                                acknowledge that your information will be transferred to Mailchimp for processing. <a
                                    href="https://mailchimp.com/legal/terms" target="_blank">Learn more about
                                    Mailchimp's privacy practices here.</a></p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div hidden="true"><input type="hidden" name="tags" value="6456416,6456520"></div>
                    <div id="mce-responses" class="clear">
                        <div class="response" id="mce-error-response" style="display:none"></div>
                        <div class="response" id="mce-success-response" style="display:none"></div>
                    </div>
                    <!-- real people should not fill this in and expect good things - do not remove this or risk form bot signups-->
                    <div style="position: absolute; left: -5000px;" aria-hidden="true"><input type="text"
                            name="b_3fa8d83aedc08e2a8814c787c_27f9c81072" tabindex="-1" value=""></div>
                    <div class="clear"><input type="submit" value="Subscribe" name="subscribe"
                            id="mc-embedded-subscribe" class="button"></div>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>

    </div>
    <script type='text/javascript' src='//s3.amazonaws.com/downloads.mailchimp.com/js/mc-validate.js'></script>
    <script type='text/javascript'>
        (function ($) {
            window.fnames = new Array();
            window.ftypes = new Array();
            fnames[0] = 'EMAIL';
            ftypes[0] = 'email';
        }(jQuery));
        var $mcj = jQuery.noConflict(true);
    </script>
    <!--End mc_embed_signup-->
    <!-- End MailChimp stuff -->

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: One last thing... The text inside the box fills in yellow, which makes it hard to read. I'm trying to find where to change that color... Help :-)

Comment: It seems the color in there is the same as the body text color. Obviously I can't change that because then it'll be unreadable against the dark blue background. Hmm

Answer (score 1):

1. Input label text shouldn't be in a separate paragraph. I've added it to the actual label.
2. Override block display and 100% width on checkboxes (set by the external stylesheet).

Other protips:

- Don't use line breaks for spacing. That's not what they're for. Use margin or padding.
- Floats are an outdated layout technique. Use flexbox, inline-block display, or CSS grid.
- Be sure to restrain the size of your image to the container. I put in a larger image placeholder and it overflowed behind the form. Set max-width.

```css
@font-face {
  font-family: museo-sans;
  src: url(/fonts/museosans_300.otf) format("opentype");
  font-display: auto;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 300;
  font-stretch: normal
}

@font-face {
  font-family: museo-sans-bold;
  src: url(/fonts/museosans_700.otf) format("opentype");
  font-display: auto;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-stretch: normal
}

@font-face {
  font-family: bwstretch;
  src: url(/fonts/BWSTRETCH-BLACK.OTF) format("opentype");
  font-display: auto;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 800;
  font-stretch: normal
}

h2 {
  font-family: bwstretch;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 2em !important;
}

* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: none;
  font-family: museo-sans;
  color: #ffc860;
}

body {
  font-size: 1em;
  background-color: #191f43;
  font-family: museo-sans;
}

#wrapper {
  width: 80% overflow: auto;
  /* will contain if #first is longer than #second */
  background-color: #191f43;
}

#first {
  width: 40%;
  float: left;
  /* add this */
  padding-left: 5%;
  background-color: #191f43;
}

#mc_embed_signup {
  width: 60% float:left;
  /* add this */
  overflow: hidden;
  /* if you don't want #second to wrap below #first */
  background-color: #191f43;
  color: #ffc860;
  font-family: museo-sans;
}

#mc_embed_signup .mc-field-group input[type=checkbox] {
  width: auto;
  display: inline-block;
}

#mergeRow-gdpr {
  margin-top: 20px;
}

#mergeRow-gdpr fieldset label {
  font-weight: normal;
}

#mc-embedded-subscribe-form .mc_fieldset {
  border: none;
  min-height: 0px;
  padding-bottom: 0px;
}
```

```html
<body>

  <!-- Start MailChimp stuff -->
  <!-- Begin Mailchimp Signup Form -->
  <link href="//cdn-images.mailchimp.com/embedcode/classic-071822.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

  <div id="wrapper">
    <div id="first"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/100"></div>
    <div id="mc_embed_signup">
      <form action="https://opipets.us17.list-manage.com/subscribe/post?u=3fa8d83aedc08e2a8814c787c&amp;id=27f9c81072&amp;v_id=4140&amp;f_id=00bb56e0f0" method="post" id="mc-embedded-subscribe-form" name="mc-embedded-subscribe-form" class="validate" target="_blank"
        novalidate>
        <div id="mc_embed_signup_scroll">
          <h2>Join our Whitelist</h2>
          <div class="indicates-required"><span class="asterisk">*</span> indicates required</div>
          <div class="mc-field-group">
            <label for="mce-EMAIL">Email Address  <span class="asterisk">*</span>
</label>
            <input type="email" value="" name="EMAIL" class="required email" id="mce-EMAIL" required>
          </div>
          <div id="mergeRow-gdpr" class="mergeRow gdpr-mergeRow content__gdprBlock mc-field-group">
            <div class="content__gdpr">
              <fieldset class="mc_fieldset gdprRequired mc-field-group" name="interestgroup_field">
                <label class="checkbox subfield" for="gdpr_90860"><input type="checkbox" id="gdpr_90860" name="gdpr[90860]" value="Y" class="av-checkbox gdpr"> I agree to receive email communications from Opis Group Ltd</label>
              </fieldset>
              
              <p>Your privacy is our policy. Occasionally, we'll contact you about our products and services, and other content that may be of interest. You can unsubscribe at any time.</p>
            </div>
            <div class="content__gdprLegal">
              <p>We use Mailchimp as our marketing platform. By clicking below to subscribe, you acknowledge that your information will be transferred to Mailchimp for processing. <a href="https://mailchimp.com/legal/terms" target="_blank">Learn more about Mailchimp's privacy practices here.</a></p>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div hidden="true"><input type="hidden" name="tags" value="6456416,6456520"></div>
          <div id="mce-responses" class="clear">
            <div class="response" id="mce-error-response" style="display:none"></div>
            <div class="response" id="mce-success-response" style="display:none"></div>
          </div>
          <!-- real people should not fill this in and expect good things - do not remove this or risk form bot signups-->
          <div style="position: absolute; left: -5000px;" aria-hidden="true"><input type="text" name="b_3fa8d83aedc08e2a8814c787c_27f9c81072" tabindex="-1" value=""></div>
          <div class="clear"><input type="submit" value="Subscribe" name="subscribe" id="mc-embedded-subscribe" class="button"></div>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>

  </div>
  <script type='text/javascript' src='//s3.amazonaws.com/downloads.mailchimp.com/js/mc-validate.js'></script>
  <script type='text/javascript'>
    (function($) {
      window.fnames = new Array();
      window.ftypes = new Array();
      fnames[0] = 'EMAIL';
      ftypes[0] = 'email';
    }(jQuery));
    var $mcj = jQuery.noConflict(true);
  </script>
  <!--End mc_embed_signup-->
  <!-- End MailChimp stuff -->

</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest using putting the checkbox and paragraph in a shared div and setting that to `display: flex;`

i.e:

```
 <div class="class">
      <fieldset>
      <p>
    </div>
```

---

```
.class {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your *input* & *label* one container apply flex

```
    <div style="display:flex">
         <input type="checkbox">
         <p>I agree to receive email communications from Opis Group Ltd</p>
   </div>
```